# Deploying multiple verticles in a parallel way

Tags: java, rx-java2, vert.x

I'm studying `Vertx.io` and `RxJava2`. What I want to achieve is to deploy some verticles altogether in a parallel way. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
  log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TheMainApp.class);
  VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions();
  Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);

  try {
    JsonObject config = getPropertyFile(args);
    Flowable<Verticle> verticlesToDeploy = Flowable
        .fromArray(new Verticle[] { new Verticle1(), new Verticle2(), new Verticle3(), ..., new VerticleN() });
    verticlesToDeploy.flatMap(verticle -> {
    return RxHelper.deployVerticle(vertx, verticle, new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).doOnError(err -> {
            log.error(err.getCause());
            throw new RuntimeException(err);
        }).doAfterSuccess(ok -> {
            log.info("Verticle {} deployed.", ok);
        }).toFlowable();
    });
  } catch (CompositeException | IOException e) {
    log.error("Deployment interrupted.");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    vertx.close();
  }
}
...
```

But it doesn't work. No verticle is deployed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `.flatMap` you don't use the resulting observable. Since the code is called within the `main` function you probably need to add `.blockingSubscribe()`